# Total digits and digits per line in C?

Tags: c, numbers, digits

Can you help me find my mistake in counting the number of digits per line and then comparing it to the total number. Here's my program that counts the number of digits per line:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

int main()
{    
    int pc, c, NumbersPerLine= 0, NumbersTotal=0, line= 1; 
    FILE *inputFile;

    if(!(inputFile=fopen("C:\\Test\\Test.txt","r")))
    {
        printf("the file does not exist\n");
        return 0;
    }

    for (pc='\n', c=fgetc(inputFile);c!=EOF;pc=c,c=fgetc(inputFile)) 
        { 
            if (isdigit(c))
            {
                NumbersPerLine++;
            }
            else 
                if (c=='\n') 
                {  
                 printf("%d %d\n", line++, NumbersPerLine); 
                 NumbersPerLine= 0;
                } 
        }     
        if (pc!='\n') printf("%d %d %d\n", line, NumbersPerLine); 
        fclose(inputFile);
}
```

But now I have to add the total number of digits in the file too and all I did was count them line by line and then sum them instead of counting them all. 
I was trying to get a result like this:

```
1 (that's the number of the line) 5 (the number of digits per line) 18 (total digits) 
2 5 18 
3 4 18 
4 1 18 
5 1 18 
6 1 18 
7 1 18
```

I tried putting NumbersTotal++; after NumbersPerLine++;, but all I got was this:

```
"1 5 5 
2 5 10 
3 4 14 
4 1 15 
5 1 16 
6 1 17 
7 1 18"
```

I also tried using do-while before 'for'

```
c=fgetc(inputFile);        
do        
{        
NumbersTotal++;        
}while(isdigit(c));
```

but after it fullfills that condition, the program ends and it doesn't continue with 'for'. Can you help me?

Comment: "per line" -> use `fgets()` instead of `fgetc()`. And that for loop is horrible.

Comment: There's nothing more annoying that getting an error message that says "The file does not exist" when it does.  Try `char *path="C:..."; if(!(inputFile=fopen(path, "r"))) { perror(path);return EXIT_FAILURE;}`

Answer (score 1):

If you read through the file once, you must either reopen the file or seek back to the beginning to read it again.  However, it would be much cleaner to read through the file only one time and keep track of both statistics during that loop.

Answer (score 1):

[Edit] Thanks to @BLUEPIXY edit, it's clearer to see that OP wants the final total printed per line.

Make 2 passes.  First to find the total, 2nd pass to do the printing.

Also use the

```
int NumbersTotal = 0;
while ((c = fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF) {
  if (isdigit(c)) NumbersTotal++;
}

rewind(inputFile);

// The rest same as OP with matching format specifiers and arguments.
for (pc='\n', c=fgetc(inputFile);c!=EOF;pc=c,c=fgetc(inputFile)) { 
  if (isdigit(c)) {
    NumbersPerLine++;
  }
  else if (c=='\n') {  
    printf("%d %d %d\n", line++, NumbersPerLine, NumbersTotal);
    NumbersPerLine= 0;
    }     
  }
}

if (pc!='\n') {
  printf("%d %d %d\n", line, NumbersPerLine, NumbersTotal); 
}
fclose(inputFile);
```

`for()` loop syntax could use some re-factoring.  Example:

```
for (pc ='\n'; (c=fgetc(inputFile)) != EOF;  pc=c) {
```

Answer (score 0):

Policy of to write intermediate results to files when it becomes a burden it is to read the file twice.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(void){
    int ch, NumbersPerLine= 0, NumbersTotal = 0, line = 0; 
    FILE *fin, *fp;
    char line_buff[32], *fname = "result.tmp";

    fin = fopen("data.txt", "r");//Check omitted
    fp  = fopen(fname, "w+");
    for(;;){
        ch = fgetc(fin);
        if(isdigit(ch)){
            ++NumbersPerLine;
        } else if(ch == '\n' || ch == EOF){
            NumbersTotal += NumbersPerLine;
            fprintf(fp, "%d %d %%d\n", ++line, NumbersPerLine); 
            NumbersPerLine= 0;
            if(ch == EOF) break;
        }
    }
    fclose(fin);
    fflush(fp);
    rewind(fp);
    while(fgets(line_buff, sizeof(line_buff), fp)){
        printf(line_buff, NumbersTotal);
    }
    fclose(fp);
    remove(fname);
    return 0;
}
```